# Php Laravel 5.1- Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]

Tags: php, email, laravel, gmail, laravel-5.1

In my `.env` i have this configuration and everything works fine on localhost:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=******

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=dbuser
DB_PASSWORD=*****

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_NAME=My app
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@private.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

But trying to send a mail online (I have GoDaddy as hosting) I get this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]
```

I'm searching for a solution but can't still find the cause.

Comment: If you are hosting it on Godaddy I would use Godaddy's mail servers to send. They might be blocking the port. If you have SSH access you could try to `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` and see if it lets you connect.

Comment: @Luca did you solve your problem? I am getting same error message

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? I am getting the same problem but couldn't find the right solution...

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you change your port and encryption to the following:

```
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I had the same problem and this helped fixed it.